# How to use 2 columns as "key" to get MAX value of selection (and on to next "key") in a SQL query

Tags: sql

using a SQL query I am trying to get a max value from multiple rows, using 2 columns as 'key', and then sum them and move on t next 'key'

Here is an example table. It has years, userid and points. Each year has several weeks.

What I want to do is to take each users MAX points for each year and SUM them.

| year | userid | week | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | **12** |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 2020 | 2 | 4 | **10** |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2021 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2021 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 2021 | 1 | 4 | **9** |
| 2021 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 2021 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 2021 | 2 | 4 | **13** |

I'd like the result for each year to be

```
User 1:
2020, 1, 12
2021, 1, 9
User 2:
2020, 2, 10
2021, 2, 13
```

...and after summing them, sorted by points:

| userid | points |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 33 |
| 1 | 21 |

...and so forth (adding on users and years)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Per Gordon's helpful answer this is the query:

```
SELECT username, userdb.userid, SUM(points) as points FROM (SELECT standing.*, row_number() over (partition by standing.userid, year ORDER BY points desc) AS seqnum FROM standing) t JOIN userdb on userdb.userid = t.userid WHERE seqnum = 1 GROUP BY userid ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select userid, sum(max_points)
from (select userid, year, max(points) as max_points
      from t
      group by userid, year
     ) uy
group by userid;
```

Alternatively, you could handle this by filtering such as by using a window function:

```
select userid, sum(points)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, year order by points desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by userid;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd also like to join this result on 'userid' from another table to get the 'username'. If you have time, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: @MonteroRo . . . You should be able to add something like `join users u on` to either query.